# 404 returned though rewrite rule is matched

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have one rewrite rule that sends all requests to `index.php`:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

It works, unless the request path starts with `index/`, in which case the result is an `404 Not Found`.

If I change the filename of `index.php` to `index2.php` (and the rewrite rule to match it), it starts working again, so clearly there's a conflict when the first segment of the filename equals the first segment of the path.

The `mod_rewrite` log contains this (when requesting `/index/hello`, which fails):

```
add path info postfix: /path/to/index.php -> /path/to/index.php/hello
strip per-dir prefix: /path/to/index.php/hello -> index.php/hello
applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php/hello'
rewrite 'index.php/hello' -> 'index.php'
add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /path/to/index.php
initial URL equal rewritten URL: /path/to/index.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

*(Some log info stripped out or modified for readability.)*

My server is `Apache/2.2.22`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: please attached complete htaccess file

Comment: @Rizwan Sultan, There's only the one rule, plus `RewriteEngine On` at the top.

Comment: Try to define RewriteBase / its only work if your website hosted on root RewriteBase /test/ if your website hosted on test folder

Comment: @RizwanSultan, I added `RewriteBase /` on line 2, but it didn't change anything. The website is hosted on root.

Comment: Unable to reproduce it. With just this rule in my .htaccess even `/index/` also goes to `/index.php` and there is no 404 in any condition. Can you show `RewriteLog` for `request path starts with index/`?

Comment: @anubhava, This rule also works perfectly for other developers on their servers, - it's just me having the problem after installing Debian on a new machine! I'm assuming there's some kind of config problem with mod_rewrite or some other Apache module. Is the log I posted not what you are requesting?

Comment: The log posted is for URI `/hello`. Can you post similar entries for `/index/` also (which should be showing 404)

Comment: @anubhava, The log posted is for `/index/hello`. I don't have any problems with just `/hello`.

Comment: As per logs there is no 404, that is just normal redirect log messages. When you comment this `RewriteRule` you will see different log indicating 404 (not found).

Comment: @anubhava, No, that is actually the rewrite log for when it fails and I get 404.

Comment: No that is NOT rewrite log for 404. That log is indicative of the fact that your `index.php` was invoked for `/index/hello`. I am suspecting you have some code in index.php OR some JS sending 404 back to you. (check http status in Firebug also).

Comment: @anubhava, I stand by what I have already said. If you don't trust me, too bad. I am not making this up and I will not make up something just to make it fit with your theory :-) Thanks for trying, at least.

Comment: Did I write anywhere that you're making it up? You're just mistaken, that's it. I asked you to check in Firebug but you're commenting on my theory though I haven't even started my theory yet. Don't you think that if if it was indeed a genuine technical problem you would have received at least an answer in last 10 hours.

Comment: @anubhava, Let's stick to the question I posted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47300/discussion-between-jgivoni-and-anubhava)

Comment: I got an answer in Serverfault in 1 hour: http://serverfault.com/questions/574831/404-returned-though-rewrite-rule-is-matched/574850#574850
Just add `Options -Multiviews` to the server conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggessted by @wrikken in Serverfault, I added this:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

[they usually don't play very nice in combination with mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#multiviews)

Comment: Answered here first: http://serverfault.com/questions/574831/404-returned-though-rewrite-rule-is-matched/574850